# Integral of cosine to integer powers

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I found the following on Wolfram Math World:

[image]

I understand the first step, the integration by parts. For the first case, m is even, I am pretty sure it involves a binomial expansion of $(\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x)))^n$, which arises from writing $\cos^{2n}(x)$ as $(cos^2(x))^n$, then writing $cos^2(x)$ as $\frac{1}{2}(1-cos(2x)$, but i do not know how they integrated from there.

Here is the link for reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case $m\equiv 2n$, one defines
$$J_n=\int\cos(x)^{2n}dx$$
Which was already shown to be 
$$\begin{align}
J_n&=\frac1{2n}\sin(x)\cos(x)^{2n-1}+\frac{2n-1}{2n}\int\cos(x)^{2n-2}dx\\
\therefore J_n&=\frac1{2n}\sin(x)\cos(x)^{2n-1}+\frac{2n-1}{2n}J_{n-1}
\end{align}$$
And we may show from induction (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3222662/583016)) that if $$f_n=\alpha_n+\beta_nf_{n-1}$$
Then $$f_n=f_0\prod_{k=1}^{n}\beta_k+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\alpha_{n-k}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\beta_{n-j+1}$$
Setting 
$$f_n=J_n\qquad n\geq0$$
$$\alpha_n=\frac1{2n}\sin(x)\cos(x)^{2n-1}\qquad n\geq1$$
$$\beta_n=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\qquad n\geq1$$
$$f_0=J_0=\int dx=x$$
Gives the desired result.